# How to print all titles in text - Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a website I want to scrape from.

The website has multiple titles, and I want to print all the titles in text.

The code I have prints the titles but not in purely text form as I use the find_all which makes them into a list.

Below is the code-

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests


titlelist=[]
url='https://www.hematology.org/meetings/annual-meeting/programs/education-spotlight'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div',class_='col')
for property in content:
    name=property.find_all('h2',class_='smaller')
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the result and print the text within each and every tag using `.text`. Replace your last `for` loop with this:

```
for property in content:
    names=property.find_all('h2',class_='smaller')
    for name in names:
        print(name.text)
```

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests


titlelist=[]
url='https://www.hematology.org/meetings/annual-meeting/programs/education-spotlight'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
content=soup.find_all('div',class_='col')
for property in content:
    names=property.find_all('h2',class_='smaller')
    for name in names:
        print(name.text)
```

Output:

```
Appropriate Use of Imaging in Patients with Lymphoma
Emicizumab’s Impact on the Landscape of Hemophilia A Treatment: Two Artists Debate the View
How to Manage Common Challenging Situations in Patients with Multiple Myeloma
Transfusion and Anemia in Global Health
Vascular Anomalies 101: Case-Based Discussion on the Diagnosis, Treatment and Lifelong Care of These Patients
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!!